# How do I overload a constructor with different subtypes of arraylists?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, constructor

I would like to initialize several different ArrayLists independantly, with separate constructors. I could easily 
achieve what I need with the class using 
only a secondary constructor aside from the default, but for the sake of knowing why this isn't working, I appreciate some insight.

```
public class MultiConstruct
{
ArrayList<Integer> first;
ArrayList<Float> second;

public MultiConstruct(){};

public MultiConstruct(ArrayList<Integer> f){
    this();
    this.first = f;
    System.out.println("MultiConstruct version one handled successfully...");
    System.out.println(" ");
}

public MultiConstruct(ArrayList<Float> s){
    this();
    this.second = s;
    System.out.println("MultiConstruct version two handled successfully...");
    System.out.println(" ");
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "it's not working"? What, specifically, isn't working?

Comment: Are you only using one of the lists at a time? Is one *always* going to be null? Btw, output in a constructor is not the best idea...

Comment: By "It's not working", I mean my ide (AIDE) tells me the app was not installed. There are no error messages, but commenting out one of these allows the program to be installed.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils The comments are only for testing. Also, I will add a constructor to initialize both at once. But for now, I just need the "hard case" dealt with.

Comment: _Type erasure_ will make the two constructors seem equal (i.e. `public MultiConstruct(ArrayList<Object> s)`) to the Java compiler -- hence the "Method MultiConstruct(ArrayList<Float>) has the same erasure MultiConstruct(ArrayList<E>) as another method in type MultiConstruct" compiler error. You need to refactor your initialization code to work around this.

Comment: @Mick Mnemonic Ok...need to do more serious study of the basics this weekend. I had no idea Java had this kind of flaw...

Comment: Yes, type erasure can be quite annoying sometimes. However, you should be able to handle your specific problem by using static factory methods (as suggested by @Rodrigo).

Comment: @Mick Mnemonic I will do that. Thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve this using static factory method instead of constructors.

At Joshua Bloch book "Effective Java" - Item 1 he describe the advantages (and disadvantages) to use static factory method instead of constructors and one of the advantages is that static factory methods have names, unlike constructors.

Comment: Very useful book. Thanks for recommending.

Answer (score 1):

You can't overload based on the parameters of a generic. `List<A>` and `List<B>` are both just 'List' at runtime. you will need to pass some sort of flag to the constructor; you probably need:

```
 <T> MyClass(List<T> list, Class<T> clazz) {
       if (clazz == Float.class) {
       } else {
       }
 }
```

I can't guarantee that this will compile. The general idea is that you need to find something else other than overloading to do your selecting.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because they have the same erasure "ArrayList" which makes both constructors have the same signature during runtime. Your best option might be to try using unbounded wildcards https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/unboundedWildcards.html
You would need to check the type with some code in the constructor and proceed from there.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a parameter to disambiguate the two

```
public MultiConstruct(ArrayList<Integer> f,   int _ignore)

public MultiConstruct(ArrayList<Float  > s)
```

It looks silly, but it is an acceptable practice.

Interestingly, this works too:)

```
    public MultiConstruct(int   ignore, ArrayList<Integer> f)

    public MultiConstruct(float ignore, ArrayList<Float  > s)

    ----

    ArrayList<Integer> list1 = ...;
    ArrayList<Float  > list2 = ...;

    new MultiConstruct(0, list1);
    new MultiConstruct(0, list2);
```

You can also define one constructor, taking in two lists

```
public MultiConstruct(ArrayList<Integer> f, ArrayList<Float> s)
```

and require that the call site supply one of the arguments as null

```
    new MultiConstruct(list1, null);
    new MultiConstruct(null, list2);
```

Comment: And what does this do to the readability/maintainability of the code? I wouldn't call such a practice acceptable. Why not just refactor the class to avoid the double constructor problem?

Comment: We don't know enough about OP's actual use case. This kind of overloading is innocent by itself; it's not an indication of design problem.

Comment: IMO, adding a dummy parameter to a method/constructor to work around type erasure is not innocent; it's a code smell.

Comment: you can always rename a method; no need for dummy there. For constructor, this is an acceptable and common workaround. It got to stink somewhere:)

Comment: I've never seen this used before in the wild; just out of curiosity, could you link to some project that uses this practice?

Comment: hmm, I can't remember, but I've definitely seen it before in JDK.